# CSS not loading on page within Magento 2 page

Tags: magento2, layout, css, page

I know this question is being asked all over Magento's stack exchange, but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to add some custom css to a page, and Chrome's console is reporting 404s when trying to load the css file. Developer mode is on, I've enabled the rewrite apache module, and my apache2.conf allows symlinks:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Chrome's console:

```
GET (404) http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/version1496785793/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/mybase.css
```

Here's my layout file (/MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/myroute_profile_edit.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/mybase.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit" name="mycompany_mymodule_profile_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tabs" name="mycompany_mymodule_profile_tabs">
                <block class="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Profile" name="mycompany_mymodule_profile_edit_tab_profile"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">profile</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">mycompany_mymodule_profile_edit_tab_profile</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\TargetProfile" name="mycompany_mymodule_profile_edit_tab_targetprofile"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">target_profile</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">mycompany_mymodule_profile_edit_tab_targetprofile</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I've also created 3 css files all having the exact same code:
MyCompany\MyModule\web\css\mybase.css
MyCompany\MyModule\view\adminhtml\web\css\myadmin.css
MyCompany\MyModule\view\frontend\web\css\myfrontend.css

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

And these are the steps I perform each time I change the css and xml files:

1. Go to the var directory and remove everything in cache, page_cache, di, and generation.
2. sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
4. Go to pub/static and remove everything except ./.htaccess.
5. sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
6. sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
7. sudo chown -R www-data:www-data magento2 (root magento dir)
8. sudo chmod -R 777 magento2
9. Clear caches.

I've tried putting each of the 3 css files in my myroute_profile_edit.xml.

```
<head>
     <css src="css/mybase.css"/> or <css src="css/myadmin.css"/> or <css src="css/myfrontend.css"/>
</head>
```

After changing myroute_profile_edit.xml, and running the above steps, I get a 404 in Chrome's console, stating mybase.css or myadmin.css or myfrontend.css could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the module that you are pulling the css from.

```
 <css src="MyCompany_ MyModule::css/mybase.css"/>
```

If you take a look into your pub/static folder, you will most likely see that your css files are correctly getting placed in your modules folder:

> pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/MyCompany_ MyModule/css/mybase.css

but the xml you have is pointing to

> pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/mybase.css

which can't find the file, as it's not there.

Comment: Thank you @circlesix, that worked! Thanks for answering so quickly, too.

Comment: glad i was able to help!